# Oracle SQL Select Unique Value AND Only one value from matching rows with non-unique values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, a master table and a general information table. I need to update my master table from the general table. How can I update the  master table when the general info table can have slightly different values for the descriptions?

**Master**

```
+------+---------+
| Code |  Desc   |
+------+---------+
|  156 | Milk    |
|  122 | Eggs    |
|  123 | Diapers |
+------+---------+
```

**Info**

```
+------+---------------+--------+
| Code |     Desc      | Price  |
+------+---------------+--------+
|  156 | Milk          | $3.00  |
|  122 | Eggs          | $2.00  |
|  123 | Diapers       | $15.00 |
|  124 | Shopright Cola| $2.00  |
|  124 | SR Cola       | $2.00  |
+------+---------------+--------+
```

As you can see item 124 has 2 descriptions. It does not matter which description.

My attempt is returning 124 with both codes, I understand my code is looking for both the unique Code and description in the master which is why it returns both 124 but I'm unsure how to fix it.

```
INSERT INTO MASTER
(
SELECT UNIQUE(Code), Desc FROM INFO A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT Code FROM MASTER B
   WHERE A.Code = B.Code )
);
```

I have also tried:

```
INSERT INTO MASTER
(
SELECT UNIQUE(PROC_CDE), Desc FROM FIR_CLAIM_DETAIL A
WHERE Code NOT IN
    (SELECT Code FROM FIR_CODE_PROC_CDE_MSTR B
    WHERE A.Code = B.Code )
);
```

Comment: You write "*I need to update my master table*" but your examples are all `SELECT` statement. What exactly do you want to do? Just display those values or actual run an `UPDATE` statement that changes the master table?

Comment: `GROUP BY Code` and `SELECT MIN/MAX(Desc)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my Insert statement in. I was working the select to identify the problem / verify the results before inserting the values because there is a need for the master table to have only unique codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique filters the duplicated entries in the `SELECTed` result set across all columns, not just one key.

When you want to extract the other attributes of a key you filtered, you have to instruct the database to first group the unique keys. To choose one of attributes of a grouped key, we can use an `AGGREGATE` function. Like `MAX()`, `MIN()`.

```
INSERT INTO MASTER
(
SELECT PROC_CDE, MAX(Desc) FROM FIR_CLAIM_DETAIL A
WHERE Code NOT IN
    (SELECT Code FROM FIR_CODE_PROC_CDE_MSTR B
    WHERE A.Code = B.Code )
GROUP BY PROC_CDE
);
```

There're [analytical functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) which can be used for even complex requirements.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, I'm still new to SQL.